# Is MySql support sp_getapplock

Tags: mysql

I just need to create transaction lock for my stored procedure until it complete,
 is it possible to use getapplock in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No but [GET_LOCK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) is roughly equivalent in that it attempts to get an exclusive lock.